# Elves, Hobbits and Dwarves

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Nice ladies kiss without men? (11)
>   6. Ask about a music style (3)
>   7. Messy ski campsite, without a doubt (10)
>   10. Performance of *Cats* troubled after loss of leading star (3)
>   11. Be familiar with singer Beyoncé, not guitarist Paul (4)
>   12. Middle-Earth city adores being in chaos (6)
>   15. Ignatius II missing after elimination of American SWAT target (4)
>   16. One who asks questions, each about operating system (5)
>   18. Penny dined on paste of *foie gras*, perhaps (4)
>   19. Only a small amount of resistance left before a riot (4)
>   21. Anti-Semite taken a Zionist's hostage (4)
>   24. Harshly criticized as Ted struck a youngling on a farm (4)
>   26. Public transport associated with a new port city (5)
>   27. Desert soldier goes around Siberian river (4)
>   29. Mashes of genuine energy sources, primarily (6)
>   30. Contamination without a colour (4)
>   32. African dictator seen from the east and the west (3)
>   33. Coordinators heart, perhaps irregular size, incorporating middle of aorta (10)
>   34. The Way of the Ancient One, originally (3)
>   35. Auditor's positions, burial places and things added afterwards (11)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Failure as exam is quicker than ever (7)
>   2. Elves' capital, losing nation's leader, born again as home of Dwarves (6)
>   3. Rest brought up amid flippant accusations (6)
>   4. It holds a flame to Keanu Reeves's character (4)
>   5. Mother stands by son as lodge member (5)
>   6. This camp is eating seafood (6)
>   8. Somewhat genuine, innocent girl (7)
>   9. Great Lakes city's introductions to man with a New Zealand accent (6)
>   13. Some kind of leading drug activity (7)
>   14. A hobbit's second breakfast is served during this part of the day (3)
>   17. Japanese religion's taboo motorcycle covered up (6)
>   20. One might go to 11 am before parking (3)
>   22. AIDS identified as cysts are reported (7)
>   23. This colour is fashionable like nothing (6)
>   25. Bruise fixed to be more active (6)
>   26. Cry about deep web mysteriously dropping dynamic header (6)
>   28. Maybe chicks remove their tops, three feet from Clapton's band (5)
>   31. Children's games making graffiti markings (4)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Completed grid:

> [image: elves_cc]

Explanation of (most) of the clues, with definition parts *italicized* and wordplay parts **bolded**:

> **Across**
>  1. *Nice ladies* **kiss without men?** (11)  = `FRENCH + WO + MEN`
>  6. **Ask about** *a music style* (3) = `(ASK)*`
>  7. **Messy ski campsite, without a** *doubt* (10) = `(SKI C(-a)MPSITE)*`
>  10. *Performance* of ***Cats* troubled after loss of leading star** (3) = `(CAT(-s))*`
>  11. *Be familiar with* **singer Beyoncé, not guitarist Paul** (4) = `KNOW(-les)`
>  12. *Middle-Earth city* **adores being in chaos** (6) = `(ADORES)*`
>  15. **Ignatius II missing after elimination of American** *SWAT target* (4) = `(-i)GNAT(-i)(-us)`
>  16. *One who asks questions*, **each about operating system** (5) = `P(OS)ER`
>  18. **Penny dined on** *paste of foie gras, perhaps* (4) = `P + ATE`
>  19. *Only a small amount* of **resistance left before a riot** (4) = `(-r)IOT + A`
>  21. *Anti-Semite* **taken a Zionist's hostage** (4) = `_NAZI_`
>  24. **Harshly criticized as Ted struck** *a youngling on a farm* (4) = `LAMB(-asted)`
>  26. **Public transport associated with a new** *port city* (5) = `BUS + A + N`
>  27. *Desert* **soldier goes around Siberian river** (4) = `G(OB)I`
>  29. *Mashes* of **genuine energy sources, primarily** (6) = `PURE + E_+ S_`
>  30. **Contamination without a** *colour* (4) = `T(-a)INT`
>  32. *African dictator* **seen from the east and the west** (3) = `IDI (palindrome)`
>  33. *Coordinators* **heart, perhaps irregular size, incorporating middle of aorta** (10) = `ORGAN + (SIZ(_R_)E)*`
>  34. *The Way* of **the Ancient One, originally** (3) = `T_ + A_ + O_`
>  35. **Auditor's positions, burial places** and *things added afterwards* (11) = `POSTS + CRIPTS`? (Seems like “crypts” is misspelled here, but maybe I’m missing something)
>
>  **Down**
>  1. **Failure as exam** is *quicker than ever* (7) = `F + AS + TEST`
>  2. **Elves' capital, losing nation's leader, born again** as *home of Dwarves* (6) = `E_ + REBOR(-n)`
>  3. *Rest* **brought up amid flippant accusations** (6) = `(_PANTAC_)<`
>  4. *It holds a flame* to *Keanu Reeves's character* (4) = `WICK (ddef)`
>  5. **Mother stands by son** as *lodge member* (5) = `MA + SON`
>  6. **This camp is eating** *seafood* (6) = `_SCAMPI_`
>  8. **Somewhat genuine**, *innocent girl* (7) = `(GENUINE)*`
>  9. *Great Lakes city's* **introductions to man with a New Zealand accent** (6) = `M_ + W_ + A + N_ + Z_ + A_`
>  13. **Some kind of leading** *drug activity* (7) = `(LEADING)*`
>  14. *A hobbit's* **second breakfast is served during this part of the day** (3) = `S + AM`
>  17. *Japanese religion's* **taboo motorcycle covered up** (6) = `_OOMOTO_`
>  20. *One might go to 11* **am before parking** (3) = `AM + P`
>  22. *AIDS* identified **as cysts are reported** (7) = `ASSISTS (homophone)`
>  23. *This colour* is **fashionable like nothing** (6) = `IN + DIG + O`? (I don’t get the wordplay for this one)
>  25. **Bruise fixed** to be *more active* (6) = `(BRUISE)*`
>  26. *Cry* about **deep web mysteriously dropping dynamic header** (6) = `((-d_)EEP WEB)*`
>  28. *Maybe chicks* **remove their tops, three feet from Clapton's band** (5) = `(-yard)BIRDS`
>  31. *Children's games* - *making graffiti markings* (4) = `TAGS (ddef)`

Comment: 35A "Auditor" cues for Homophone.

Comment: 23D rot13( Snfuvbanoyr = VA, Yvxr = QVT, Abguvat = B )